# Passing a PHP variable using Javascript Void 0 as the HREF?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a page that allows a user to edit a user. The table gives me the row ID which is in the button shown below. It works fine when having it direct to another script. However, I wanted to open the users details dynamically which this program does.

Although I don't understand where to place the $row to have the page be able to access it? My research was more about just passing between both programs when I just need to link it up.

I just want this to when the button is pressed, send the $row['usersid'] variable to the page which I can then use.

EDIT: It seems I've confused both myself and you all. I want to keep this in PHP if possible. All I need is the $row['usersid'] or a variable that stores it which is in PHP currently. To be sent to the page without it refreshing.

```
echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick=".$row['usersid']."' id='showButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";

echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'".$row['usersid']."' id='showButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";
```

Comment: show your code and which section you face problem

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam forgive me, I'm not used to how it formats the code. I placed it in the href and onclick but to no avail the variable is not passed.

Comment: Since you're using PHP you can send it as a GET variable. For example `echo "<td><a href='page.php?user=" . $row['usersid'] . "' id='showButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";`

Comment: you want to link other page using this value?

Comment: echo 'function test(x)  { alert(x); }';  change onClick=".test('".$row['usersid']."')

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign This is done on a single page therefore it is not refreshed.

Comment: @Subi and what does this do?

Comment: @ParagonJenko  u'll get the value of $row['userid']  on button click

Comment: you want to store this value save ? then use ajax or use session

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass the information in page to another one, let me list some of them:

1. approach

```
echo "<td><a href='/path_to_another_php_page.php?userId=$row['usersid']' onClick= id='showButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";
```

then you can access to this information searching in `$_GET['userId']`.

2. If your want to use this userId, only for make ajax request, you could do simply doing:

```
echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' data-user-id='$row['usersid']' onClick= id='showButton'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";
```

as you can see I added a `data-user-id` attribute that contains the real `userId` from php, so in your Javascript you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("showButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
var userId = this.getAttribute("data-user-id");
// here you can call your ajax ...
}, false);
```

I hope this be useful for you.

Comment: Alexander O'Mara thank you for edit the answer, I was facing some trouble with the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check your value then use this code which you get your value

you can also get data using this code

```
  <?php 
      $row['usersid'] = 10; // fot test case 
      $row['usersid1'] = 13; // fot test case 
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.getValue', function(){
            // send data to PHP
            var id = this.getAttribute("userId");
            alert(id)
        });

        </script>
    <?php
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class = 'getValue' userId = ".$row['usersid']." id='showButton'>Button</a></td>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class = 'getValue' userId = ".$row['usersid1']." id='showButton'>Button</a></td>";
```

this is second option

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getValue(value){
            alert(value)
        }

        </script>
    <?php
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick=getValue(".$row['usersid'].") id='showButton'>Button</a></td>";
```

Comment: hope it will help you

Comment: adding non standard attributes to an html element is not the best practise - the `dataset` attribute was designed for such use-cases so I would suggest using that instead of random attributes such as `userid`